# Send json data via angular http post to laravel controller

Tags: json, angular, laravel, http, post

I’m new in laravel and angular. I tried to send some data from a service to a function in a laravel controller.
Here my laravel code:

```
public function authenticate(Request $request){
    file_put_contents('test.txt','run');

    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Request-With');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');

    $name=$request->input('name');
    $password=$request->input('password');
    $message='Not Found';

    $user=User::where(['name'=>$name])->first();
    if($user->checkPasswordAttribute($password)){
        $message='Found';
    }
    return response()->json([
        'message' => $message,
    ]);
}
```

Here my angular service code via json:

```
login(user: User): Observable<User> {
return this.http.post<User>(this.usersUrl, user, httpOptions).pipe(
  tap( _ => this.log('fetched user')),
  catchError(this.handleError<User>(`getUser`))
);
```

}

with this HttpHeaders:

```
const httpOptions = {  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type':  'application/json' })};
```

Above code send nothing, not even run file_put_content, that I add for test.
But when I use formData as below code in angular service, everything is ok and run my backend code.

```
login(user: User): Observable<User> {
const postData = new FormData();
postData.append('name', user.name);
postData.append('password', user.password);
return this.http.post<User>(this.usersUrl, postData).pipe(
  tap( _ => this.log('fetched user')),
  catchError(this.handleError<User>(`getUser`))
);
```

}

Can someone advice me?

Comment: First of all, did you check your `logs`  in 'storage/logs/*' what is the actuall issue.

Comment: Tank you, I checked logs an it show this error message "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/api/user' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.". so I use this website http://tekina.info/cors-problem-laravel-angular/ and it solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

This will decode the http request json payload.

```
$data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
```